# jqplot, remove outside border

Tags: jquery, css, jqplot

How to remove outside borders of jqplot, Please take a look at following screenshot.
I tried with different options and searched for it, ButI didn't get a solution.
[image]

Here is my code,

```
plot1 = $.jqplot(container, [data], {
        title: 'title',
        animate: true,
        animateReplot: true,
        seriesColors:['#00ADEE'],
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            shadow: false
        },
        axesDefaults: {
        },
        highlighter: {
            tooltipAxes: 'y',
            show: true,
            tooltipLocation: 'sw',
            formatString: '<table class="jqplot-highlighter"> \
      <tr><td>test:</td><td>%s</td></tr></table>'
        },
        grid: {borderColor: 'transparent', shadow: false, drawBorder: false, shadowColor: 'transparent'},
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks:ticks
            },
            yaxis: {
                max:1000
            }
        }
    });
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

---

Here is the JsFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/JWhmQ/2551/), I want to remove the outside border.

Comment: can you prepare a jsfiddle

Comment: but how to remove them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can register a custom function in [postDrawHooks](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/index/Hooks.html), to be fired after plugin initialization.

The idea is to use this function to draw a white border rectangle on top of the chart, that makes the outside borders invisible.

```
$.jqplot.postDrawHooks.push(function() {
    var $canvasMain = $("#chart1 canvas.jqplot-grid-canvas"),
        $canvasLines = $("#chart1 canvas.jqplot-series-canvas"),
        canvasSize = { 
            x: parseInt($canvasLines.attr('width')), 
            y: parseInt($canvasLines.attr('height'))
        },
        ctx = $canvasMain[0].getContext('2d');

    ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
    ctx.lineWidth = 6; // 6 to hide shadows and the larger bottom side
    ctx.rect($canvasLines.position().left,
             $canvasLines.position().top,
             canvasSize.x,
             canvasSize.y + 3);
    ctx.stroke();    
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JWhmQ/2562/)

You can see that the outside borders are gone:
[image: Sample output]

This works fine, but personally I would just go ahead and modify the source to skip the outside borders. The plugin is double licensed with GPLv2 and MIT, so I guess there are no problems going that route.

### Solution 2

I found out that if you change this

```
grid: {borderColor: 'transparent', shadow: false, drawBorder: false, shadowColor: 'transparent'},
```

to

```
grid: {borderColor: 'white', shadow: false, drawBorder: true},
```

the outside border disappears (kind of what I do above), but still some tick marks on x axis appear. I've set `showTickMarks: false` to no success.

See [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JWhmQ/2563/)

Answer (score 6):

The outside border is not a jqPlot border, *they are the outermost gridlines*. Hence to remove this "border" you will need to turn the gridlines off.

You can turn off these gridlines by adding:

```
drawGridlines: false
```

to your grid properties e.g.

```
grid: {
 drawGridlines: false,
 borderColor: 'transparent',
 shadow: false,
 drawBorder: false,
 shadowColor: 'transparent'
}
```

As you have the highlight option enabled, this will be a viable option for you, as you can see the point values when you hover over them.

Comment: No, I know it. I want to remove outside border, not inside gridlines

Comment: What you are asking for is not possible, as you are not seeing borders, you are seeing the gridlines. To remove the outer most gridlines you need to turn the grid off.

Comment: Sorry If I'm wrong, It's my client requirement. Anyway Thanks.

Comment: No problems @SrihariGoud.

Answer (score 1):

Simply setting `drawBorder:false` worked for me:

```
grid: {drawBorder: false},
```